# How can I save UIPickerView rows selection

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uipickerview

I have an UIPickerView with 2 components.
I would like to save the user's selection for the components.
How can I do that?
I have tried with NSUserDefaults but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't `NSUserDefaults` help?  Were you unable to get it working or did it not meet your requirements?

Comment: I used these settings to save:

    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:row forKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults synchronize];



and these settings to load:


    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pickerView selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"] inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Comment: Guy Dor: I strongly suggest defining a macro for each of your defaults keys. Having a typo in one instance of one of them will drive you mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used didSelectRow. I'm create UILabel and whrite text from picker there. array1, array2 - NSMutableArray with text from components.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    selection[component] = row;
        [self updateText];
}

-(void)updateText 
{
label.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ g/L", [array1 objectAtIndex:selection[0]], [array2 objectAtIndex:selection[1]] ];
}
```